# too many re-renders. React limits the numbers of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a picker with a button that not show for the first time (disabled)

```js
const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
```

When I select from the picker I want to verify with condition if the first select is `"please select"` I disable the button else I enable it .

```js
const getctg2 = (val) => {
  val != "please select" ? setDisabled(false) : null;
};
```

The `Button` code

```js
<Button
  style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
  title="add Car"
  disabled={isDisabled}
  onPress={() => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
    addCarlist();
  }}
></Button>
```

The error msg that I get after that is:

```js
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

NB: when I replace inside the condition: `setDisable(false)` with`console.log('active button')`

With the console there is no error and I detect with the message console the right moment to enable but when I change with the `setDisable(false)` to get the button I get the error.

Comment: `after that`: after what? . Also, it will be easier for others to help you if you share a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: the repo is private i cant import to Sandbox ! after that i talk about the message error .. Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.